# MVC "Editfor" Element for a "List<string>" with the option to add new elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, editorfor, editorfortemplate

I need way to display a "List" property with the option to add new elements to the list.

So Basically

> - Value 1
> - Value 2
> - Button: Add new

I created an editfor template for it, where I display all the values with a foreach loop. However, each item get's an index, so when I add a new input field with javascript, the index is wrong.

Any suggestions how to achieve this.

PS: the adding of new elemens mustbe done on the client, since it is a simple form

Comment: Can you show your loop code?  If you are using a `foreach`, this won't work.

Comment: yeah; I'm using a for loop. I got that foreach doesn't work because it adds the name you defined in the foreach statement to the form. However I still need a way to add the index...

Comment: When you render your view, save the `Count`  to a JavaScript variable. You'll know then what the next available index is.

Comment: isn't there some standard widget which might do this for me?

Comment: None that I'm aware of...

Comment: See my answer on this question. It might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286797/how-to-handle-repeating-form-fields-in-asp-mvc/25287349#25287349

Comment: [Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some further example of how to dynamically add objects to a collection

Answer (score 0):

```
    var abccounter = 1;

    $("#abcbutton").click(function () {

        $('#itemlist').append('<p><input class="text-box single-line" id="listofstringname_' + abccounter + '_" name="listofstringname[' + abccounter + ']" type="text" value=""></p>');

        abccounter++;
    });


<p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.listofstringname)</p>
```

that is what I did and it worked. the only problem I'm having (and it may be solved eventually) is I want to wrap each element with a

tag but I'm not sure how. this JS just adds a new "text box element" assuming 1 as the start as my model loads 1 example by default.