# Add/update/delete element in a list in a form asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I use ASP.NET MVC 5.
I am trying (without success :|) to create a form and one of the parameters of this form is a list. I am in trouble about how to add/remove/update element for this list.
I tried a lot of different samples (with ajax, kendo ui and more) with no success.

**Simplified problem:**

I want to be able to add House information in a database.
Each House got information and a list of Occupants

Details:
- my occupants are not saved anywhere. so no access to a db or other
- there is nothing created before I press the Create House button. Everything as to stay/be created in this page
- the solution can even use kendo ui
- I am looking for a very simple solution :)

Thanks a lot!

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int HouseID { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int RoomsCount;

    public List<Occupant> OccupantsList { get; set; }
}

public class Occupant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Create House page**

```
@model DeveloperConsole.Models.House

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Houses</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @RenderBody()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>House</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
                </dt>

                <dd class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                </dd>

                <dt class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomsCount)
                </dt>

                <dd class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomsCount)
                </dd>

                <dd class="form-group">
                    @if (Model.OccupantsList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OccupantsList[0].Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OccupantsList[0].Age)
                                </th>
                            </tr>

                            @foreach (var template in Model.OccupantsList)
                            {
                                Html.RenderPartial("Occupant", template);
                            }

                        </table>
                    }

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="button" value="Add an Occupant" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" name="command" value="Create House" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Occupant partial view**

```
@model DeveloperConsole.Models.Occupant

<div class="editorRow">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
        </td>

        <td>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                &lt;input type="button" value="Delete this Occupant" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to dynamically add new `Occupants` to a `House` in the form?

Comment: Yes, dynamically as a House can have a different number of Occupants.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) shows some approaches you can use to dynamically add new elements to the DOM and be able to post back and bind the collection.

Comment: The answer here might help you too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286797/how-to-handle-repeating-form-fields-in-asp-mvc/25287349#25287349